# Javascript regex repeated capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

I ma trying to match following exact format: '7b3bda24-31db-44d4-aa7f-7012b3594623' but without success.

```js
var reg = new RegExp('/^([a-f0-9]{8})-(([a-f0-9]{4})-){3}([a-f0-9]{12})$/i');

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = reg.test('7b3bda24-31db-44d4-aa7f-7012b3594623')
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Replace `(([a-f0-9]{4})-){3}` with `([a-f0-9]{4})-([a-f0-9]{4})-`

Comment: It is either `var reg = new RegExp(/^([a-f0-9]{8})-(([a-f0-9]{4})-){3}([a-f0-9]{12})$/i);` or `var reg = new RegExp('^([a-f0-9]{8})-(([a-f0-9]{4})-){3}([a-f0-9]{12})$', 'i');`

Answer (score 3):

The `RegExp` constructor accepts a string regular expression (no slashes). If your regular expression is not dynamic, just use a regular expression literal.

```js
const reg = /^([a-f0-9]{8})-(([a-f0-9]{4})-){3}([a-f0-9]{12})$/i;
console.log(reg.test('7b3bda24-31db-44d4-aa7f-7012b3594623'));
```